# Alarm not triggering on Redmi devices

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have an alarm application. Alarm is not triggering on Redmi devices. Screen wake lock and ringing when app is in background is not working exactly.

Please find the alarm manager and wake lock code I have used

a)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        alarmTime,
                        operation
                )
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        alarmTime,
                        operation
                )
```

b)

```
val wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
            "a:TAG"
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true)
            setTurnScreenOn(true)
        }
        wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/)
        window.addFlags(
            LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED or
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD or
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON or
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        )
```

I found that when we allow screen lock and allow running in background app works. Is there any way to add the specified permission for redmi devices in order to work when app is in background and to wake screen lock pragmatically or  any other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true for many more manufacturers. (see dontkillmyapp.com/) What you can do, is to check which phone it is and ask them to whitelist your app through settings. (Settings and locations of whitelists may vary from device to device)

Comment: hi @GiorgosNeokleous i have tried adding auto start permissions for app ,still issue exist

Comment: That won't do it, you will have to ask for whitelisting.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous how to do that?adding battery optimazation in settings?